# windows phone7 socket programming?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

how to make Windows phone7 suport socket programming? is  a solution here?

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't support it yet. Though Microsoft has announced that they will add it in the future. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7) for more information (the *Announced APIs* section).

Comment: how soon will Microsoft added it ?